Can I somehow tell apart user-triggered clicks and programmatic ones?
When a dialog window is first opened, I need to programmatically select an option (a JRadioButton) and do X
When the user selects an option, I need to do Y
X is a subset of Y
In both cases, the radios should be visually selected
How do I achieve it?
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class RadioButtonDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel();
        JRadioButton radioOne = new JRadioButton("Radio One");
        JRadioButton radioTwo = new JRadioButton("Radio Two");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        Stream.of(radioOne, radioTwo).forEach(r -> {
            group.add(r);
            radioPanel.add(r);
            r.addItemListener(e -> {
                // designed for user selections only
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) doY();
            });
        });
        JButton button = new JButton("Show dialog");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {
            JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(radioPanel, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION);
            JDialog options = optionPane.createDialog(frame, "Options");
            radioOne.setSelected(true);
            options.setVisible(true);
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void doY() {
        doX();
        doZ();
    }

    private static void doX() {
        // do something
    }

    private static void doZ() {
        // do something else
    }
}


You can define a flag (a boolean variable, for example) which is set to true when programmatically clicked and false when user clicks the button.

Since the programmatic initialization is done before the dialog is shown, you can check r.isShowing() to tell the initialization and a later-on selection apart.

@prasad_ flags smell bad

You can try  using an enum.

@Holger that's an interesting suggestion, thank you

alternative, add the listener after doing the programmatic initialization

@demavi "smell bad"? really? I've seen that quite often

@user85421 it's because smelly code is commonplace
